# Binary Search Tree Iterator - In/Pre/Post Order

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have a class `BinarySearchTree` which has two data elements, `Node root` and `int size`. The `Node` class has four data elements `Node left, right, up` and `int data`.

I want to create an Iterator class whose constructor takes in what type of traversal it's going to be using. It iterates over the next element only when `next` is called.

What data elements should be in `MyIterator` so that this doesn't get messy? I am thinking maybe to have `Stack<Node>` but that feels like a really bad solution. Is there anything clever I can do to cover all three of the possible modes? Is there any way to do this without having an additional data structure (queue/stack/map) inside of the Iterator?

```
public class MyIterator
{
    private BinarySearchTree tree;
    private Node current;
    private int mode;

    public MyIterator(BinarySearchTree tree, int mode)
    {
        // mode = 1 -> IN ORDER TRAVERSAL
        // mode = 2 -> PREORDER TRAVERSAL
        // mode = 3 -> POSTORDER TRAVERSAL

        this.tree = tree;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void next()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Morris Inorder Tree Traversal and variations on it are the structure/algorithms that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like a use case for the strategy pattern. Your Iterator's constructor should get the actual *ModeStrategy* as parameter instead of a plain *int*. The strategy is stored in a class attribute. *ModeStrategy* could be an interface looking something like this:

```
public interface ModeStrategy {
    boolean hasNext(BinarySearchTree tree, Node current);
    void next(BinarySearchTree tree, Node current);
}

public class MyIterator {
    private final ModeStrategy mode;
    // other fields omitted
    public MyIterator(BinarySearchTree tree, ModeStrategy mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    // your methods delegate to mode
}
```

Comment: That is my intention but I am using `int` to simplify the quesiton down to the core problem which is the data elements/algorithm that would go inside the Iterator

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to introduce a factory pattern and split your implementation into own `Iterator`s.

```
final class IteratorFactory {
  enum Mode {
    IN_ORDER, PRE_ORDER, POST_ORDER;
  }

  private IteratorFactory() {
  }

  public static <T> Iterator<T> get(Mode mode, BinarySearchTree<T> tree) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mode);
    Objects.requireNonNull(tree);
    switch(mode) {
      case IN_ORDER: return new InOrderIterator<T>(tree);
      case PRE_ORDER: return new PreOrderIterator<>(tree);
      case POST_ORDER: return new PostOrderIterator<>(tree);
      default: throw new AssertionError("Can't happen");
    }
  }

  private static class InOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    //...
  }
  private static class PreOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    //...
  } 
  private static class PostOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not split the implementations. Instead I'd rather have instance variables that cover the needs for all situations. This is for reasons outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: You were asking _What data elements should be in MyIterator so that this doesn't get messy?_. If you don't split your concerns it's already messy IMHO.